Where have I come from?

How do you live your life?
Where have I come from?
Is there a supreme being?
What is happiness? How can we obtain happiness?
What is the “Good”?
Why do bad things happen to good people?
Can we ever know anything for certain?
What will happen to us when we die?


Wittgenstein Tract. 6.521 - "The solution of the problem of life is seen in the vanishing of this problem." Tract. 7 - "Whereof one cannot speak, thereof one must be silent."
(https://www.wittgensteinproject.org/w/index.php?title=Tractatus_Logico-Philosophicus_(English))

@Rwin Hello, and welcome to PhilSE! Please read https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/help This question needs improvement, particularly picking one your questions and expanding on it. See https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask And don't take closure personally.  You can get more clarification at https://philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com/

I vote to reopen this post because the questions are philosophically relevant.  @Rwin is a new contributor who made his/her entree with some stimulating questions - different than so many other participants for 1 day. - I ask for indulgence with him for not satisfying the formal rules with his first post.


Different people live their life in different ways, with
different aims and values.
There is no generally accepted answer. The
individual answer depends on a personal choice, often dependent on
the circumstances.

You - like all others - are the child of your parents.
If
you ask, where does the human species come from, then: According to
the theory of evolution humans are one of the many species on earth.
All species have common ancestors.
There exists also a scientific
theory how life on earth could have developed from interacting
chemical processes in environments with certain physical properties.

Atheist’s say no, theists say yes, agnostics say: I don’t
know!  One has to study the arguments of each group and make his/her
decision.

There is no general answer. But I consider it always a good
way to find out: What are my strenghts, what helps my neighbours or
my bigger social groups, where do I feel satisfaction?

The “Good” is an abstraction. It is the noun with the
highest positive connotation.
But its content is totally
indeterminate. Many philosophers during the history of philosophy
have propagated different contents.

Events often happen at random.
The blueprint of the universe
does not pay attention to the human species – according to the atheists’
worldview. While theists and worldviews like Buddhist and Hindu
views hypothesize the existence of a moral causality.

Knowing for certain is rather seldom, in most cases we rely on
confirmed hypotheses.
Replacing the search for ultimate justification by the principle of falsification is the position of critical rationalism, propagated by the philosophers Hans Albert and Karl Popper.

The human species is one among millions of other species.
Concerning the question of death, humans have no reason to assume
that their fate is different than the fate of other species: The
individual dies, the life processes come to an end, the chemical
structure decays – and the next generation takes over.


Please note that some answers are opinion-based and are controversely discussed.  See also the general hints for this blog at help.

As to 7 - The uncertainty of beliefs, the perceived lack of knowledge is one of the core discoveries that set science and philosophy going. It's a bit strange to attribute this to Popper - since it's really the old Chinese, Indian and Greek sceptics that hammered on this, starting several centuries BCE...

@mudskipper I expanded my answer to 7 to clarify my point. - It seems that often your and my answer are compatible. I am curious what other participants say.

So you can not be certain that you know your own observations and memories? Not what you deduce from them based upon your own individual logic if you had one?

@JoWehler - "Atheist’s say no, theists say yes, agnostics say: I don’t know!" "There is no general answer" - I think this concept of "non-question" is silly and wrong. There are definitive answers about our reality. It is just that most of us are not ready for them, yet.


Breath in and breath out. I don't know how. It seems to be happening all by itself.
I don't know. I don't really known what "I" or "you" refers to.
I don't know. I don't know what the words "supreme being" are intended to refer to. Perhaps it is you or me?
You know it when you feel it. It seems best, in order to
obtain it, not to search for it and not to think too much about it.
A meaningful life. And what is a meaning of a life? The life that is lived is the meaning.
Things just happen. Why would nature care about us?
No. We can never know anything for certain. Uncertainty
is what drives scientific enquiry. We need uncertainty as much as we need (presumed) certainty. (Before you start to get smart, let me say from the outset, that I'm not certain of any of the statements I'm making here. I'm not even sure that I'm making any "statements".)
It depends on what you mean by "you", "I" or "we". Your atoms will be recycled. But are those "you"? When I listen to Glenn Gould playing Bach, aren't Glenn Gould and Bach literally still alive? The traces you leave behind, do they only "express" you? What's the difference between "being you" and "expressing you"?

Confronted with questions like these, especially question 5, I almost automatically revert to Wittgenstein's answers in the Tractatus -- even though I cannot accept those anymore because they are too absolutist and therefore non-sensical --

6.43 - The world of the happy is quite another than that of the unhappy.


+1 For a brave attempt. Let the OP note that an absurdist rejects many of the questions at meaningless.
